# BERT masked lenguaje model. How can calculate the embedding of the MASK token?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, transformers

On the training step of the masked lenguaje model, we constuct the embedding of the "masked" token using the embeddings of the contextual words, right? Then with a softmax layer we predict the "masked" word".

If we construct the "masked" embedding with the contextual tokens, we would need to calculate the dot product of the query of the "masked" embedding and the key of each contextual tokens. My question is....how can we calculate the query of the "masked" token if we dont know the input embedding of it (because we "masked" it intentionaly)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The very first inputs to the Transformer are token embeddings: this is just a static lookup for each token. At that stage `[MASK]` is a token just like any other one. Because of that, the gradient that propagates through the entire network to the input embeddings, including the `[MASK]` one.

The task of the output layer is to guess what was the token that was replaced by the `[MASK]` token. To do so, the network needs to get the information from the context, but that does not remove the `[MASK]` embedding from the input.

Comment: Perfect answer. Another question in the original article BERT selects 15% of the tokens for a possible replacement. Of the chosen tokens, 80% are replaced with the [MASK], 10% are left unchanged, and 10% are replaced by a randomly selected vocabulary token.

RoBERTa also uses this strategy? That is, predict tokens without using the [MASK] token... What is the purpose of that?